# are session variables saved after query execution when using connection pool?

Tags: mysql, database-connection, session-variables, connection-pooling

I am struggling to understand how session variables are managed when using a connection pool on every documentation I am reading the definition of session variable is

> Session variables
>
> Session variables are set in the scope of your session with the MySQL
> server.
>
> A session starts with a connection to the server and ends when the
> connection is closed.
> Variables go out of scope once the connection is terminated.

for example :
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0201__Procedure-Function/LOCALSESSIONANDGLOBALVARIABLESINMYSQL.htm

if we're using a connection pool the connection is not really getting close or terminated
does it mean we need to reset the session variable at the end of the transaction?